# Progress bar fails when loaded second time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, android-progressbar

I have a simple function that shows loading spinner while fetching data (usually takes 7 seconds or so)

```
private void load_data(View v)
{
    task_complete = false;
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setMessage("Fetching data ...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.show();

    try
    {
        Log.v("thread", "Starting thread");
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!task_complete)
                {
                    fetch_data();
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
        Log.v("thread", "Thread finished successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("thread", "fail "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the function gets called by onClick via

```
load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        load_data(v);
        show_data(v); // shows the data on a spinner
    }
});
```

And when I press the load button the second time I get an error. My log does show

```
Starting thread
Thread finished successfully
```

But somehow the app dies with an error saying

```
03-27 02:48:39.282: E/AndroidRuntime(956): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
03-27 02:48:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(956): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-27 02:48:39.293: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can show me or explain to me what causes the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your progressBar.dismiss(); is executed in another thread, to make it run in UI thread, do this:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for an awesome answer, it works, and all I had to do is change one line :)

Comment: The thread will start running on UI thread, which may prompt ANR (Activity Not Responding) dialog, if the loading takes slightly longer time. However in your case it just takes 7 seconds for loading, so the user won't mind ;)

Comment: actually only the progressBar dismiss command will be executed on UI thread, which I would be surprised if it takes more than 0.1 msec.

Answer (score 1):

`ProgressDialog` is a View and you can access it in the UI thread (or main thread) only. Use `AsyncTask` instead of threads.

**EDIT**
[This official link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) will help you get the hang of AsyncTask. The thing to remember is doInBackground() method runs in separate thread where you should put your data loading method i.e. fetch_data(). Once the method completed execution, onPostExecute() will get called, which will run on UI thread, where you can dismiss the dialog. You can start the dialog in the onPreExecute() method.
Though in this context you do not need the onProgressUpdate() method, but just FYI, it is used to update the Views in UI thread while the loading is still working using publishProgress() call (In case you use the AsyncTask in future).

**PS:** Only the doInBackground() method runs in separate thread, every other method runs in UI thread. The rule about not accessing the View in any other thread except the UI one, still applies here.

Comment: PS: Reply if you don't know how to use AsyncTask, I'll update my post.

Comment: Updated the post, have a look there :)

Comment: I've wrote a blog post for the same, check it out, if you want more info about AsyncTask - http://abhishek347.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/asynctask-on-rescue/